# Encrypting home folder in advanced installation

Tags: system-installation, encryption, partitioning

I'm trying to install Ubuntu and have my home folder encrypted.

When running the installer, there is a checkbox to encrypt the Ubuntu installation. However this option is only available if I choose the option "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" (which I don't want to do)

[image]

Instead I choose "Something else" in order to manage the partitions as I like. I create a swap partition, a root partition and a home partition.

But here I don't see any option to encrypt my home partition, and if I click "Install Now" the installation begins.

[image]

How can I encrypt my home partition without erasing the full disk? Or do I have to encrypt AFTER the installation is done?

Thanks

Comment: You are confusing encryption of full partitions (using LUKS, if I remember correctly) and encryption of the home folder using ecryptfs.

Answer (score 0):

After clicking "Install now" I just realized that after couple of screens there is the option of encrypting the home folder when installation asks for admin username and password.

This may solve my own question.

[image]